# Automatically drop a temporary table when the transaction is over

Tags: mysql, database, temp-tables

I need to create a temporary table and perform a few SELECTs on it. After that I won't need that temp table. But since I'm using a connection pool, the temp table will stay there and will even interfere with the next transaction that happens to acquire the same connection.

My question is, is there a way to automatically clean-up the table when my current transaction is over?

Obviously, I could do that manually, but in order to do it properly, the code won't be that simple:

```
<START TX>
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS some_tt;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE some_tt AS ...;
...
<use some_tt here>
...
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS some_tt;
<END TX>
```

In order to release resources, we should drop the table as soon as we don't need it anymore (before the tx ends). But since we cannot guarantee the drop will happen & succeed, I believe we should also execute a drop right before the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statement, just in case.

Comment: MySQL removes the temporary table automatically when the session ends or the connection is terminated. Of course, you can use the  DROP TABLE statement to remove a temporary table explicitly when you are no longer use it.

Comment: You can't use multiple connections, even connections from the same pool, to perform transactions or access temporary tables. Both those things have connection scope.

Answer (score 0):

A TEMPORARY table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed. However, temporary tables are not affected by transactions and are not deleted when a transaction ends or rollbacks. In addition, the temporary table is visible to parallel transactions within the session.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).